# Problem texturing sphere using triangle strip

Tags: java, opengl

I am learning opengl but having problem rendering sphere. I can draw and bind the texture of polygon normally but when I try to use the same method to the sphere drew by triangle strip, it just didn't went well. Part of the texture is broken. (Pic on below)

May I know what did I do wrongly? Sorry if this is an obvious question.

Here are the code of sphere : 
(before adding the texture part, the sphere can be displayed normally)

```
private void drawSphere(GL gl) {
        Position spherePosition = state.getSpherePosition();
        final float PI = 3.141592f;
        gl.glPushMatrix();
        if(spheretexture == null){
           setSphereTexture();
        }

        gl.glTranslated(spherePosition.getX(), spherePosition.getY(), spherePosition.getZ());
        float[] ambientDiffuse = new float[] {255.0f, 255.0f, 255.0f, 1.0f};
        gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL.GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, ambientDiffuse, 0);

        gl.glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        gl.glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        float x, y, z, alpha, beta; // Storage for coordinates and angles
        float radius = 25f;
        int gradation = 10;
        for (alpha = 0.0f; alpha < PI; alpha += PI / gradation) {
        spheretexture.enable();
        spheretexture.bind();
        gl.glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
        for (beta = 0.0f; beta < 2.01 * PI; beta += PI / gradation) {
            x = (float) (radius * Math.cos(beta) * Math.sin(alpha));
            y = (float) (radius * Math.sin(beta) * Math.sin(alpha));
            z = (float) (radius * Math.cos(alpha));
            gl.glTexCoord2f(beta / (2.0f * PI), alpha / PI);
            gl.glVertex3f(x, y, z);
            x = (float) (radius * Math.cos(beta) * Math.sin(alpha + PI / gradation));
            y = (float) (radius * Math.sin(beta) * Math.sin(alpha + PI / gradation));
            z = (float) (radius * Math.cos(alpha + PI / gradation));
            gl.glTexCoord2f(beta / (2.0f * PI), alpha / PI + 1.0f / gradation);
            gl.glVertex3f(x, y, z);
        }

        gl.glEnd();

        spheretexture.disable();
        gl.glDisable(GL_BLEND);
        gl.glPopMatrix();
    }

    }
```

Output picture: [image: img]

Comment: What is the issue? Is the [Depth Test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Depth_Test) enabled?

Comment: my bet is you got a seem at the 0 = 2PI angle if the case you need to duplicate the last chunk of triangles to avoid having whole texture in the single triangle ...

Comment: @Rabbid76 Sorry that I didn't explained my problem clearly. I have rendered the sphere with the photo but part of the texture is broken. I have added the output picture on the bottom of post.

Comment: @Spektre Sorry that I didn't explained my problem clearly. I have rendered the sphere with the photo but part of the texture is broken. I have added the output picture on the bottom of post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major issue is that the top cap of the sphere is drawn twice. That causes [Z-fighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting). Note, first it is drawn buy the strip between `PI-PI/gradation` and `PI` and then it is drawn by the strip between `PI` and `PI+PI/gradation`. That is caused, because the outer loop does one an extra pass. Change it to:

```java
for (alpha = 0.0f; alpha < PI-PI/gradation; alpha += PI / gradation) {
    // [...]
}
```

or even better

```java
for (int i = 0; i < gradation; ++ i ) {
    float alpha =  PI * (float)i / (float)(gradation);
    // [...]
}
```